# fpga communication with pc

Tags: java, communication, vhdl, fpga

Ok i am using Spartan 3a kit and i need to know the simplest and safest choice to communicate with my fpga with my pc , meaning to send data to input pins of connector and receive from the pins of the output pins of connector
Now this connector or interface , i cant choose , What i know is that i have this interfaces on my fpga :
RS232
Ethernet
USB(only for proggramming, i think)
Differential pair ports (???)
ADC/DAC ports 
PS/Keyboard and mouse ports

No i need a suitable interface so that i can create a program on pc (with java probably) and be able to send data to be input to my fpga implementation.

IT has to be able to support at least 7 Mega Byte / second, so RS232 wont work.

Please if any help if possible and a little hint on how interface would be done on pc and fpga is really appreciated

Comment: @Desolator: No, Logic design is in the middle between physical layer and SW programming. Computer engeneering links computer science with silicon/electronics. So, it is as much appropriate to SO as it is to the electrical engeneering. The appropriate place for logic design questions is http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45270/logic-design. It is banned though. So, please do not say that Omar is in a wrong place.

Comment: I would suggest you look into using UDP via Ethernet. On a 100Mbit interface, the data rate you require should be achievable. This will provide you with a very easy and well supported interface on the PC side. On the FPGA side, cores and/or demonstrations of implementing Ethernet interfaces are available.

Answer (score 1):

Of those, only Ethernet is (a) common to the host PC and (b) fast enough for your purpose. That makes it an easy choice. Look at the Xilinx website for demonstration projects using the Ethernet interface.